# Grails rejectValue - multiple checks causing ob.errors null

Tags: grails

My domain object booking has multiple attributes that are allowed to be null, because they will be set later after the object has been saved to the db.

Part of myService.action():

```
booking.properties = params    

if (booking.contactFirstname?.length() <= 1) { booking.errors.rejectValue("contactFirstname", "empty") }
if (booking.contactLastname?.length() <= 1) { booking.errors.rejectValue("contactLastname", "empty") }
if (booking.contactPhone?.length() <= 1) { booking.errors.rejectValue("contactPhone", "empty") }
if (booking.contactMobile?.length() <= 1) { booking.errors.rejectValue("contactMobile", "empty") }
if (booking.contactEmail?.length() <= 1) { booking.errors.rejectValue("contactEmail", "empty") }    

if (booking.hasErrors() || ! booking.validate()) { 
    return [success: false, model: booking]
} else {
    booking.save(failOnError: true)
    return [success: true, model: booking]                
}
```

My controller does:

```
def result = myService.action(params)
if (result.success) {
    flash.success = message(code: "msg.successfullySaved")
    redirect(action: "registerEventConfirmation", id: result.model.uid, params: [lang: params.lang], mapping: "paginated")   
} else {
    flash.error = message(code: "msg.errorSavingCheckFields")
    render(view: "registerEventStep3", params: [lang: params.lang], model: [booking: result.model])
```

I'm using
    hasErrors(bean: booking,field:'contactFirstname', 'has-error')}

to mark error fields.

If I now submit the form without any values in textfields, all fields are red, booking.errors has >0 errors.

If I submit the form after with a firstname, booking.errors is NULL and no other field is marked.

Is this a Bug? I'm with Grails 2.3.6

**additional information**

1. I visit the form, submit it empty completely
2. I see all form fields in red, object.errors has >0 errors (VALID)
3. I enter a value in the first field, firstname and submit
4. I see none of the form fields in red, object.errors =0 errors (INVALID)
5. I re-submit the form with none changes
6. I see all empty form fields in red, object.errors has >0 errors (VALID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I fully understand the situation and since I was having trouble sleeping I thought I give you a very concise answer so that you can hopefully make full sense and use things properly.

Firstly I know creating a validation bean sounds like it will be a lot of work so let me teach you how to do it all relatively simply and why it is my preferred method.

It is my preferred method simply because when you do

class MyController {

```
 def myAction(Mybean bean) {
   // 1. the object allowed into this save action 
   // are all that is available objects withing MyBean. 
   // If it has user define but not telephone. Then
   // if telephone is passed to myAction it will fail and not recognise 
   // field
   // When declaring Date someField or User user then the params now 
   // received as bean this way is now actually properly bound 
   // to the data / domainType declared. 
   // Meaning user will now be actual user or someField actually Date 
  }
```

So now to explain how to best solve this issue. When creating beans simply copy over the actual domain class from your domain folder into `src/groovy/same/package` in grails 2  or `src/main/groovy/same/package` in grails 3

Change name / class or copy as from `Booking` to `BookingBean` so it has a different name.

Add `@Validateable` above actual `BookingBean` in grails 2  or add implements to main class like `Class BookingBean implements Validateable {`  in grails 3

Now since it is copied all the objects are identical and at this point a save from the controller would be

```
class MyController {

     def myAction(BookingBean bean) {
         Booking booking = new Booking()
         // this will save all properties
         booking.properties = bean
         booking.save()
     }
}
```

But you have a special circumstance and you wanted to declare a transient field in the main domain class what I would do instead is

```
class BookingBean {
  def id
  String contactFirstname
  String contactLastname
  boolean secondSave=false

 static constraints = {
     id(nullable: true, bindable: true)
    contactFirstname(nullable:true) //,validator:checkHasValue)
    contactLastname(nullable:true) //,validator:checkHasValue)
    secondSave(nullable:true,validator:checkHasValue))

}

//use the same validator since it is doing identical check

static checkHasValue={value,obj,errors->
    // So if secondSave has a value but contactFirstName 
    // is null then complain about contactFirstName
    // you can see how secondSave gets initialise below
    //typical set this to true when you are about to save on 2nd attempt
    //then when set run validate() which will hit this block below

    // Check all the things you think should have a 
    // value and reject each field that don't
    if (val) {
        if ( !obj.contactFirstname) {
            errors.rejectValue('contactFirstname',"invalid.contactFirstname")
        }
        if ( !obj.contactSecondname) {
            errors.rejectValue('contactSecondname',"invalid.contactSecondname")
        }
        //and so on
    }
}
```

So now in your controller:

```
class MyController {

     def save1(BookingBean bean) {
         Booking booking = new Booking()
         // this will save all properties
         booking.whatEver = bean.whatEver
         booking.save()


 // you can choose to validate or not here
 // since at this point the secondSave has 
 // not been set therefore validation not called as yet in the bean

     }
```

//you probably have id and it should bind with actual domain class

```
def save2(BookingBean bean) {

         booking.secondSave=true
         if (!bean.validate()) {
            //this is your errors 
            //bean.errors.allErrors
            return
         }
         //otherwise out of that loop since it hasn't returned
         //manually set each object 
         booking.contactFirstname=bean.contactFirstName
         booking.contactSecondname=bean.contactSecondname
         booking.save()


     }
```

}

**e2a side note - above should answer**

well don't validate it until you have created it. Only validate it after you created the object then added a value. Alternative create a function possibly in a validation bean that you run as part of your 2nd check. [This Example bean](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-bean-validation-examples/blob/master/src/main/groovy/testing/PhotosBean.groovy#L82-L83) is not validated [until formatRequest](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-bean-validation-examples/blob/master/src/main/groovy/testing/PhotosBean.groovy#L112-L113) is called [as seen here](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-bean-validation-examples/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/testing/PhotosController.groovy#L57-L65)

Comment: The domain model has nullable true since I create the object now and persist it. After changing to another page, I want to do a validation to certain fields and therefore, want to validate the fields afterwards. Can I pass some args with validate() in order to do the extra-check when I request it?

Comment: As per above the field is nullable and only when it has a val or value it will attempt to validate that value. So in short you can save it as it is currently saving with no value. The moment it gets a value it will attempt to validate that according to the checkHasValue validation set hence   if (val && val.length()<=2) { as in if there is a val and val.length is less than 2 then complain. It sounds like it will do what you need to do

Comment: this sounds logically, but: the validation shouldn't be activated if some value is provided, but in a process step that comes after the creation of the object: 1. creation of the object, 2. display form and validation. Your validator only fires if a value is passed and does not match the length.

How would you create this?

Comment: The world is your oyster you choose how /when  to validate I updated asnwer

Comment: The world is your oyster you choose how /when to validate I updated asnwer. The exam provided captures error in try catch - doesn't go into encapsulating the errors you could use booking.errors.allErrors.collect{g.message(error : it)}  to collect all errors if it didn't validate as a basic example

Comment: You say I can validate when I want, but the validator will also be called when I do obj.save(). So this doesn't work for me. Can I work with a transient variable "checkDetailFormData" that will be set before I need to validate the details and will be a condition in the validator? Tried, but I cannot access a variable in a static way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123870/discussion-between-john-schmitz-and-vahid).

Comment: I have updated and given a more understandable answer hopefully

Answer (score 1):

I don't grasp the specifics of your question, so I will give some general guidance since I have just dug into this.

1. Don't call hasErrors() before validate(). If you do, Grails won't hand you errors from domain constraints and you will only end up with the errors you set yourself using rejectValue().
2. Be careful with using rejectValue(). Try to set all your errors using domain constraints. If you have sophisticated constraints use the validator syntax and obj.getPersistentValue() might be your friend once in a while.
3. If you still have to use rejectValue(), understand that any later calls to validate() will start from scratch and erase your prior errors. I have written a workaround for this (to be placed in your domain object) although I can't assure you it is 100% ok:

`def validateWithErrors(def fields = null) {
  def existingErrors = this.errors
  def ret = (fields ? this.validate(fields) : this.validate())
  existingErrors?.allErrors?.each { error ->
    this.errors.rejectValue(error.field, error.code)
  }
  return (existingErrors?.allErrors ? false : ret)
}`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I totally agree with #1 and #3. #2 I agree partially, see comment to post no 2, I don't think this can be solved with validator on domain model since I want to do a validation after I saved an object.